# "Read this post in our app!" on WP which has no app

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

Visiting StackOverflow on my Windows Phone phone using Internet Explorer, I am presented a banner that wants me to "Read this post in our app". This banner links to a search in the Windows Phone app store which sadly does not offer a StackOverflow app.

This banner makes no sense in a browser which clearly indicates by the user agent that it runs on an OS for which no StackOverflow app is available.

The banner should only be displayed in browsers that run on systems that are supported.

Comment: The logical fix for this is to make a Windows Phone app :-)

Comment: Of course. But let's not get greedy ;)

Comment: WP user too. It could be worse. Some sites are completely unusable because of hovering banners forcing you to download an app that doesn't exist. SO's notification is quite friendly in that regard.

Comment: @JonasCz Well, the UI is agreeable and I don't feel it's really necessary.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood the *real* meaning of this message. It simply suggests you to get a different OS so you can install the app. ;-)

Comment: If SO provides me with the funds needed to buy a phone with a supported OS, I'd be glad to do this :D

Comment: I thought it was SO provides you with the resources necessary to get a job to pay for a phone with supported OS

Comment: @humble.rumble I have such a job which allows me to 1) contribute to SO, 2) buy the phone I like. But note that I'm not asking for a phone, or an app. I suggest to improve the UI of the mobile web version of SO, that's all.

Comment: I use cyanogenmod, is there an app for me without using Google Apps? Please, don't show me this message over and over again. I don't care.

Comment: Every time I see that prompt, dismissable though it is, whether on Android or iOS, I can't help but think of this [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1174/); though in fairness the SO app is better than most. But I still prefer to use the website.